# StructureMap - How to make different instances of an interface (by different constructor values) for use in constructor of different classes

Tags: c#, structuremap

I have this class and interfaces:

```
Public interface IBook{
}

public class Book:IBook
{
    public Book(int num){
        //...
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------

Public interface IBox{
}

Public interface IBoxA:IBox{
}

Public interface IBoxB:IBox{
}

Public interface IBoxC:IBox{
}

//------------------------------------------------------

public class Box1:IBoxA
{
    public Box1(IBook myBook, ..........){
        //...
    }
}

public class Box2:IBoxB
{
    public Box2(IBook myBook, ..........){
        //...
    }
}

public class Box3:IBoxC
{
    public Box3(IBook myBook, ..........){
        //...
    }
}
```

I want pass the Book object to constructor of `Box1`, `Box2` & `Box3` by `StructureMap` IOC but each one should has different value in their constructor.

Really I want a mechanism to determin witch `Book` objects (witch witch parameter value) should be passed to the witch `Box` class. It is a condition for instancing `Box` classes.

For a better explanation please see the following image:

[image]

I write the following config:

```
For<IBoxA>()
   .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
   .Use<Box1>();

For<IBoxB>()
   .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
   .Use<Box2>();

For<IBoxC>()
   .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
   .Use<Box3>();

ForConcreteType<Box1>()
        .Configure
        .Ctor<IBook>("myBook")
        .Is(new Book(1));

ForConcreteType<Box2>()
        .Configure
        .Ctor<IBook>("myBook")
        .Is(new Book(2));

ForConcreteType<Box3>()
        .Configure
        .Ctor<IBook>("myBook")
        .Is(new Book(3));
```

But really `Box1`, `Box2` and `Box3` has many parameter in their constructors and one of them is `IBook myBook`. I don't know how can I set a config to just set `myBook` parameter in the constructor of `Box1`, `Box2` and `Box3` with appropriate object.

---

**Edit1:**

My real project is different and I tried to simplify my question by reduce names and relations of it, then it is possible that I have some mistakes in the real project but I get an error like it:

`No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'IBook' There is no configuration specified for 'IBook'`. Should I define another config for IBook in the above scenario?

My code **has not** another config for `IBook` »» `Book` because `Book` has a constructor with parameter and value of its parameter is depended on where (in witch `Box`) it is.

Comment: So what's wrong again with configuration you provided (last block of code)?

Comment: @Evk, do you recommend this way or another method?

Comment: I'm not sure yet, just trying to figure out if it does what you need and if yes - what you don't like about it.

Comment: @Evk, my real project is different and I tried to simplify my question by reduce names and relations of it, then it is possible that I have some mistakes in the real project but I get an error like it: `No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'IBook' There is no configuration specified for 'IBook'`. Should I define another config for `IBook` in the above scenario?

Comment: @mjwills, I updated the question with more codes and made some changes in its interfaces and classes to be more similar to the real project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what goes wrong where in your real example, but in general all you need is:

```
c.For<IBoxA>()                    
    .Use<Box1>()
    .Ctor<IBook>().Is(new Book(1));

c.For<IBoxB>()                    
    .Use<Box2>()
    .Ctor<IBook>().Is(new Book(2));

c.For<IBoxC>()                    
    .Use<Box3>()
    .Ctor<IBook>().Is(new Book(3));
```

And resolve using interface (so `IBoxB` and not `Box2`):

```
var box = container.GetInstance<IBoxB>();
```

Comment: Thank you... I changed my configs based on your pattern and the problem solved. I don't know what different between my configs and yours but your config is shorter and works.